# How reference & change single row TD element with on change event

Tags: javascript, html, reference

Help!  I have spent all day trying to resolve this issue.  I have a table which includes (among other data) a ProductId and a ProductDescription.  I have created a javascript change event, which retrieves the assocaited ProductDescription whenever the ProductId changes.  The ProductDescription is retrieved via a call to a method in my C# (asp.net) program.  That part is working correctly.  The issue I am having is in referencing the table row in which the ProductId has changed; when my jquery event is fired, the ProductDescription field is updated on ALL rows in the table (not just on the row that changed).

I have looked at so many examples, but cannot find the correct syntax to update only the row in which the ProductId was changed.  As you will see from my screen shots below, the ProductDescription is updated on ALL rows in my table according to the ProductId (in a single row) that was modified.

Here is my code:

[[image: enter image description here]]

[[image: enter image description here]]

[[image: enter image description here]]

When I set the first Product ID in the table (with value PM08), I want the program to populate (only) the first Product Description in the table with the associated description (POSTUPS MOUNTS), but I am not referencing this element properly, and so ALL Product Descriptions are updated with the value as shown below:

[[image: enter image description here]]

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to index the the row that changed and update ONLY the Product Description for that row.

Thanks in advance if you have the solution!

Comment: [Please don't post images of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2745495). Codes are text so post them as text. It would also make it easier for potential helpers to copy your code to their own editors so that they can reproduce the problem. Please see the **Code Blocks** section of the [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) help page.

Comment: Thanks, Gino.  I attempted to do this, but as a first-time user (ever), I could not figure it out.  I'll follow the help link above next time.

Comment: I still have no replies to this, so I'll break it down into a simple problem.  In the Javascript section at the top of this post, I have a $.get block which returns on productDescription value.  I wish to set ProductDescription cell on one row (same row where the Product ID was changed) of the table to this value.  Currently, the entire Description column is being set to this value (i.e. on all rows).